# Duplicate field for parent Object in One-to-One mapping Spring Hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am making a simple REST API and I have 2 dB entities - User and an Account.
Account basically holds information about the user and each user has only one account (One-to-One mapping). I am new to Spring so I would be happy if someone can help me with this.

When I make a GET request to /api/v1/account, it has both user and appUser. When I make a request to /api/user i get users without the "account" field. Can someone explain me what is going on and a potential fix for this issue? I also accept any suggestions on something that can be improved.

```
[
    {
        "accountId": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "filip",
            "password": "kucherenkov"
        },
        "name": "filip",
        "surname": "kucherenkov",
        "appUser": {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "filip",
            "password": "kucherenkov"
        }
    }
]
```

This is my user model:

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user")
public class AppUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Account account;

    public AppUser() {

    }

    public AppUser(String email, String password){
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

 ... simple getters and setters
```

This is my account model:

```
@Entity(name = "Account")
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long accountId;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private AppUser user;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

//    @Column(name ="date_of_birth")
//    private Date date_of_birth;



    public Account(){

    }

    public Account( String name, String surname){
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
... simple getters and setters.
```

Account controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/account")
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    private AccountService accountService;

    public AccountController(AccountService accountService){
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    List<Account> getAccounts(){
        return accountService.getAccounts();
    }

    @PostMapping("/new")
    int addAccount(@RequestBody Account account){
        return accountService.addAccount(account);
    }
}
```

user controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
@RestController
public class AppUserController {

    private UserService userService;

    public AppUserController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/specific")
    AppUser getUserByEmail(@RequestBody JsonNode json){
        return userService.getUserByEmail(json.get("specific_email").asText());
    }

    /**
     * @return List of all users registered in the app.
     */
    @GetMapping
    List<AppUser> getAllUsers(){
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user.
     * @param user - User object containing details of the user to create.
     * @return TODO: Make an appropriate error handling.
     */
    @PostMapping
    int addUser(@RequestBody AppUser user){
        return userService.addUser(user);
    }
}
```

Account service:

```
@Service
public class AccountService {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final UserService userService;


    @Autowired
    public AccountService(AccountRepository accountRepository, UserService userService){
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.userService = userService;


    }

    public List<Account> getAccounts(){
        return accountRepository.findAll();
    }

    public int updateAccount(Account newAccount){
        accountRepository.save(newAccount);
        return 1;
    }


    public int addAccount(Account account){
        AppUser currentUser = userService.getUserById(1);

        Account _newAccount = new Account(account.getName(),account.getSurname());
        _newAccount.setUser(currentUser);
        currentUser.setAccount(_newAccount);
        userService.updateUser(currentUser);
        System.out.println(_newAccount.getAccountId());
        AppUser user = userService.getUserById(1);
        System.out.println(user.getAccount().getAccountId());


        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The AppUser is child Tabel so that `@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")` need be there in child Tabel. you have to move `mappedBy` to parent entity.

You have interchange everything

Comment: I've made it like this because I was thinking of having a table Account that had an FK userID to the user table. Isn't the Account table the parent in this case?

Comment: So user is parent and child is account.

Comment: Json managed refer need be in parent. Json back reference in the child.

Comment: Interchange the JSON references.

Comment: switched them both but now I get `non-transient entity has a null id: `

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem using `@JsonIdentityInfo` instead. As mentioned below, it is better to have the User entity as a parent instead. However, I don't think it was the root cause of the problem. If someone can add something more I would really happy to read :)